# State changes in the react native functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want the Calender changes its language depends on the user language (there are 3 languages can be chosen in the app, English Spanish and Italian), English is the default language of the calendar library. Btw the library uses moment.js to use different languages.
But the calender language is not changed when I change the user language.
I need to help to fix this

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import React, { FunctionComponent, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NETWORK_ONLY, useQuery } from 'relay-hooks';
import { AuthenticationContext } from '../providers/authentication/AuthenticationProvider';
import CalendarStrip from 'react-native-calendar-strip';
import moment from 'moment';

import USER_BY_ID, {
  relayGetUserByIdQuery,
} from '../__generated__/relayGetUserByIdQuery.graphql';
interface Props {
  selectedDate: Date | Moment;
  setSelectedDate: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Date | Moment>>;
}

const WeeklyCalendar: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  const { selectedDate, setSelectedDate } = props;
  const { userData, refreshQuery } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  const { data } = useQuery<relayGetUserByIdQuery>(
    USER_BY_ID,
    { id: userData?.userId || ''},
    { fetchPolicy: NETWORK_ONLY }
  );

  // The localization rules are the same as moments for adding localization to react-native-calendar-strip component
  useEffect(() => {
    refreshQuery();
    if (data?.user?.language == 'ES') {
      require('moment/locale/es');
    }
    if (data?.user?.language == 'IT') {
      require('moment/locale/it');
    }
  }, [data?.user?.language])

  return (
    <CalendarStrip
      scrollable
      style={{ height: 75 }}
      calendarHeaderStyle={{
        color: '#3D3D3D',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '500',
      }}
      dateNumberStyle={{ color: '#3D3D3D' }}
      dateNameStyle={{ color: '#3D3D3D' }}
      highlightDateNumberStyle={{ color: 'white' }}
      highlightDateNameStyle={{ color: 'white' }}
      highlightDateContainerStyle={{
        borderRadius: 10,
      }}
      iconContainer={{ flex: 0.1 }}
      numDaysInWeek={7}
      daySelectionAnimation={{
        type: 'background',
        duration: 200,
        highlightColor: '#2975D6',
      }}
      selectedDate={selectedDate}
      onDateSelected={(date) => setSelectedDate(date)}
    />
  );
};

export default WeeklyCalendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your index.js and import the specific "Locale" after the main moment import

```
import 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';  // language must match config
```

Comment: If I import 2 or more languages I need
```
import 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';
import 'moment/locale/it';
```
In that case it reads only the last imported language, but I need to do something depends on the chosen language in the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'moment/min/locales'
```

and set you moment with

```
data?.user?.language == 'ES' ? moment.local('ES') : moment.local('IT')
```